# Send data between WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

So I have been looking around and haven't found a solution for this, using WPF `Window`s.

So what I want to do is to send values from two sliders from one WPF `Window` to another. How should this be done using two WPF `Window`s inside the same project? And is it possible to do it from another project inside the same solution using references?

I have been working with Windows forms and can get it to work easily there, but it just won't work with WPF `Window`s.

[Edited] What needs to be done is very basic really. We have a menu Project called `Startup` with a `MainWindow.xaml` that does not yet contain any code that needs to be mentioned. Although, we want from the menu, to be able to use 2 sliders, 1 to set the amount of players that are going to participate and another to set the amount of hours that the game should last. We have fixed this problem already from the game itself by setting the amount of players like this:

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)  // Change move-army-strenght
{
    movearmy = Convert.ToInt32(slider1.Value);
    lblresult3.Content = "" + movearmy;
    if (menuphase == 1) { players = Convert.ToInt32(slider1.Value); }
}
```

This will check if it's `menuphase` one and then get the amount of players from that. Although, we want to send this value from the `Menu`, not while inside the game!

Comment: There is a plethors of directions to go. If you would be willing to share the objective, we could help you pick the right one much easier. :) EDIT: By 'Objective", I mean the actual use case.

Comment: Please provide some more information. What code are you using in your Winforms application? If we could see some code we might be able to determine why it doesn't work with WPF.

Comment: Updated! Added after [Edited] in the text.

Comment: @ThommyJonasson you have serious issues here. First of all, there's no such thing as a "form" in WPF. There are `Window`s. Second, you are bringing a winforms mindset and trying to use that in WPF. you will fail. You must learn the MVVM pattern and understand that `Data is not UI, Data is Data and UI is UI.` What you need to share between your windows is data values, not UI elements' properties. This can be accomplished using regular CLR objects to hold your data and implementing the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I agree with HighCore that applying the MVVM pattern for WPF projects in general is essential, and if your two windows can be bound to a common view model class instance, then a change in values from your sliders (bound to view model properties) can change other values (if the view model properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged).  If you are needing to pass data between windows in different projects, I would use the Mediator design pattern (in addition to MVVVM).  I've used the Mediator to do things such as passing data between independent tool windows within Visual Studio packages.

Comment: The problem is done and the solution is posted on the question spot! Thanks for taking your time guys! I have taken notes of what you guys have written and will study into that more.

Answer (score 2):

It may well be overkill for your requirements, but an extensible way to send messages with data between forms, windows, etc. is to use the [Mediator Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx).  There is an excellent article and sample project by Marlon Grech for a [WPF Mediator](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/03/20/more-than-just-mvc-for-wpf/).

This pattern works well for sending a variety of messages, so long as there aren't too many subscribers looking for the messages.

Answer (score -1):

The OP wrote in an edit:

> [SOLUTION]
>
> ```
> public partial class SelectionWindow : Window
> {
>     WpfApplication1.GameWindow newForm2;
>
>     public SelectionWindow()
>     { InitializeComponent(); }
>
>     private void continue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (Convert.ToInt32(slider1.Value) > 1)
>         {
>             Worldmap.Properties.Settings.Default.value1 = Convert.ToInt32(slider1.Value);
>             Worldmap.Properties.Settings.Default.value2 = Convert.ToInt32(slider2.Value);
>             Worldmap.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
>             newForm2 = new WpfApplication1.GameWindow();
>             newForm2.Show();
>             Close();
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void slider1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
>     { playerresult.Content = Convert.ToInt32(slider1.Value); }
>
>     private void slider2_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
>     { timeresult.Content = Convert.ToInt32(slider2.Value); }
> }
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)).